# Should [operator-map] be a synonym for [map-operator]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A quick search for the two tags ([map-operator](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-operator) and [operator-map](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operator-map)) shows little difference between the two.

[map-operator](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-operator) has a nice wiki, which [operator-map](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operator-map) lacks.

I'm not sure what other information is relevant or needed: I see no difference between the tags, and the one is clearly better cared for.

Thoughts?

Comment: I definitely agree. I've proposed the synonym, so feel free to vote on it.

Comment: I don’t have the requisite tag score @DJMcMayhem , but thanks for doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged the two tags using the mod merge tool. This also created a synonym.